# R: Filter two columns but not if column A contains these values

Tags: r

I have a df with a 'Previous' and a 'Current' column. I want to filter the df so that only rows exist when the 'Previous' value is equal to the 'Current' value UNLESS the 'Previous' value starts with "YJA", "NIO" or "GRADE". I know how to compare the two columns like so but don't know how to add the exception:

```
df <- df(Current == Previous)
```

How do I say to do this filter unless the 'Previous' column is equal to "YJA", "NIO" or "GRADE"?

Thanks

Comment: please share at least a subset of the data with either `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `&` and `!`:

> unless the 'Previous' column is equal to "YJA", "NIO" or "GRADE"

```
subset(df, Current == Previous & !Previous %in% c("YJA", "NIO", "GRADE"))
```

or:

> UNLESS the 'Previous' value starts with "YJA", "NIO" or "GRADE"

```
subset(df, Current == Previous & !startsWith(Previous, c("YJA", "NIO", "GRADE")))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Current Previous
  <chr>   <chr>   
1 a       a       
2 b       b       
3 c       c
```

Data

```
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(Current = c("a", "b", "c", "YJA", "NIO", "GRADE", "y"), Previous = c("a", "b", "c", "YJA", "NIO", "GRADE", "x"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. OP (also) ask for an exact match: *unless the 'Previous' column is equal to "YJA", "NIO" or "GRADE"?*? but I've added a solution to the other situation mentioned as well.